# Generate consecutive years ranges from array of years in PHP

Tags: php

I have array:

```
'years' => 
array (size=28)
  0 => string '1985'
  1 => string '1986'
  2 => string '1987'
  3 => string '1988'
  4 => string '1989'
  5 => string '1990'
  6 => string '1991'
  7 => string '1992'
  8 => string '1993'
  9 => string '1994'
  10 => string '1996'
  11 => string '1997'
  12 => string '1998'
  13 => string '1999'
  14 => string '2000'
  15 => string '2001'
  16 => string '2002'
  17 => string '2005'
  18 => string '2008'
  19 => string '2011'
  20 => string '2012'
  21 => string '2013'
  22 => string '2014'
  23 => string '2015'
  24 => string '2016'
  25 => string '2017'
  26 => string '2019'
  27 => string '2020'
```

What is the fastest way to generate ranges of consecutive years from this array?
My goal is to accomplish exactly this array:

```
array(
0 => '1985-1994',
1 => '1996-2002',
2 => '2005',
3 => '2008',
4 => '2011-2017',
5 => '2019-2020'
);
```

Years 2005 and 2008 don't have consecutive years, so are inserted alone.
Array list of years would vary ofcourse.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: BRAVO. You can write your own answer, you can then also accept it as the correct answer. That is a better way of signalling others that it is a correct answer

Comment: @Johnconde can I ask for a reopen vote, OP fixed it themselves and posted the answer in the question

Comment: @mihaichelaru Can I ask for a reopen vote ^^^

Comment: @Robert You should post your answer as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If someone would need a solution to such a problem, there is a ready code below.

```
$range_started = 0;
$ranges = [];
$last_year = end($years);

foreach($years as $year) {
    if (!$range_started) {
        $range_started = $year;
        $next_expected = $year+1;
        
        continue;
    }
    
    if ($year == $next_expected) {
        $next_expected++;
        
        if ($year < $last_year)
            continue;
    }
    
    $ne = $next_expected-1;
    
    if ($range_started < $ne)
        $ranges[] = $range_started . '-' . $ne;
    else
        $ranges[] = $range_started;
    
    $range_started = $year;
    $next_expected = $year+1;
}
```